# Cannot access shared folder on another Ubuntu machine

Tags: networking, samba

I have ubuntu 15.10 installed on two PCs.

On PC A I have shared the /home folder (as a result samba + other were installed automatically).

From PC B I can see the folder but when I try to open it I just get this greyed out screen:

[image]

Before getting that screen I did select **Registered User** and typed the user and password for the user I use to login to PC A.

How do I access the shared folder from PC B?

Is there some mandatory checklist that I need to go through to make this work, since it apparently is not something that works out of the box?

I made it work using this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!

And connecting using this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you configure correctly :

1. `adduser john`
2. `addgroup users`
3. `sudo chown -R john:users folder`
4. `sudo chmod -R 0770 folder/`
5. `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`

And add following lines:

```
[folder]
path = /home/samba/folder
valid users = john
guest ok = no
writable = yes
browseable = yes
security = user
```

6. `/etc/init.d/samba restart`
7. `sudo usermod -a -G users john`
8. `sudo smbpasswd -a john`
9. enter passwd: