# Cannot download files to SMB shared folder

Tags: permissions, smb

I have shared a folder on machine **A** running Ubuntu, see [Cannot access shared folder on another Ubuntu machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707496/cannot-access-shared-folder-on-another-ubuntu-machine) for details.

On machine **B** (also running Ubuntu), I can access this shared folder through `nautilus` (read/write content). But, when I try to download a file using **B** in Chrome and specify the destination as the shared folder on **A** it fails.

Why can't I download directly to the shared folder on **A** from **B**?

Comment: May be the specified destination is incorrect. You've not mentioned the exact detail, so there is no way to know.

Comment: I selected the destination using the File Chooser dialog box so its not possible to select something that does not exists/is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to mount the network share in **/etc/fstab** so its mounted at start up and that solved the problem and I can now download to the share.